# Confusion with source-map-explorer analyzer in ReactJs project

Tags: reactjs, npm, optimization, build, source-maps

I have a moderately sized React project, and the production build size of the main.xxxx.js file is too large (19.3 MB). I'm trying to reduce it.

After some googling, I learnt the first step is to analyze my build files to see what code are contributing to the size, so I gave [source-map-explorer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/source-map-explorer) a go.

This is what was generated (cropped to show the relevant section):

[image: Analysis results from source-map-explorer]

Somehow, `objectWithoutPropertiesLoose.js` constitutes 86% of the build size. But when I go to check the file in the node_modules folder, the size is only 1KB and the content is just:

```
export default function _objectWithoutPropertiesLoose(source, excluded) {
  if (source == null) return {};
  var target = {};
  var sourceKeys = Object.keys(source);
  var key, i;

  for (i = 0; i < sourceKeys.length; i++) {
    key = sourceKeys[i];
    if (excluded.indexOf(key) >= 0) continue;
    target[key] = source[key];
  }

  return target;
}
```

I'm probably misunderstanding something so I'd like some pointers. Thanks.

Here's my `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "clientapp",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@microsoft/applicationinsights-react-js": "^3.3.4",
    "@microsoft/applicationinsights-web": "^2.8.4",
    "@microsoft/signalr": "^6.0.6",
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.5",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.3.0",
    "@testing-library/react-hooks": "^8.0.1",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^14.2.1",
    "@types/bootstrap": "^5.1.12",
    "@types/file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "@types/jest": "^28.1.3",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.5.14",
    "@types/moment": "^2.13.0",
    "@types/node": "^18.0.0",
    "@types/popper.js": "^1.11.0",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.14",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.5",
    "@types/react-pdf": "^5.7.2",
    "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.24",
    "@types/react-rnd": "^8.0.0",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.3.3",
    "@types/reactstrap": "^8.7.1",
    "@types/resize-observer-browser": "^0.1.7",
    "@types/textarea-caret": "^3.0.1",
    "@types/video.js": "^7.3.42",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "country-state-city": "^3.0.1",
    "cropperjs": "^1.5.12",
    "enter-view": "^2.0.1",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "jest-each": "^28.1.1",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "jquery-cropper": "^1.0.1",
    "rc-drawer": "^4.4.3",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-custom-scrollbars": "^4.2.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-pdf": "^5.7.2",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.2",
    "react-rnd": "^10.3.7",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "reactstrap": "^9.1.1",
    "redux": "^4.2.0",
    "source-map-explorer": "^2.5.2",
    "textarea-caret": "^3.1.0",
    "util": "^0.12.4",
    "video.js": "^7.19.2",
    "xss": "^1.0.13",
    "workbox-background-sync": "^6.5.3",
    "workbox-broadcast-update": "^6.5.3",
    "workbox-cacheable-response": "^6.5.3",
    "workbox-core": "^6.5.3",
    "workbox-expiration": "^6.5.3",
    "workbox-google-analytics": "^6.5.3",
    "workbox-navigation-preload": "^6.5.3",
    "workbox-precaching": "^6.5.3",
    "workbox-range-requests": "^6.5.3",
    "workbox-routing": "^6.5.3",
    "workbox-strategies": "^6.5.3",
    "workbox-streams": "^6.5.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "build-sw": "react-scripts build && react-scripts start",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "copy-pdfjs-worker": "copy ./node_modules/pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.worker.js public/scripts/pdf.worker.js",
    "analyze": "source-map-explorer 'build/static/js/*.js'"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "source-map-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "ts-loader": "^9.3.1",
    "typescript": "^4.7.4",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.10.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are some of the ways you can reduce the Bundle Size effectively. But first of all, make sure you are using production build.

1. If the source map is very confusing for you, you can use [webpack analyzer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-bundle-analyzer). Once you identify the bigger component you can optimize it. Like using alternative packages, removing unnecessary packages, etc.
2. Second thing you can do is code splitting in your react app using `React.lazy()`. You can read about this [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html). For starters, you can start with Route base code splitting and then further.
3. Minification can also significantly reduce the size of your bundle. For example, if there are comments, large variable names, white spaces, etc can be reduced.
   You can use something like [Terser](https://terser.org/) to minify your code.
4. This method helped us significantly to reduce the overall loading time. You can use compression techniques to compress the size of the bundle so that it can travel in a shorter time over the network. This method reduced the size by over 70% in our use case.
   Some famous Compression algorithms are Gzip,Brotli etc, which are widely supported by all kind of browsers.